# Кастомизация компонента vue-select

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Я использую компонент https://sagalbot.github.io/vue-select/. Хотелось бы предоставить пользователям возможность редактировать уже выбранное значение. (на картинке выбран текст "sometest", хотелось бы чтобы при повторном выборе оно не размывалось, а пользователь мог редактировать его.). В документации не нашёл такой возможности, возможно кто то делал похожее.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: и что потом должно произойти с отредактированным значением? а вообще может вам нужен [tagging](https://sagalbot.github.io/vue-select/docs/Basics/Values.html#tagging)?

Comment: просто нужен доступ к редактированию, потому что есть похожие данные которые подтягиваются из api и пользователь может совершить ошибку. tagging использую для ввода значений которых нет в api

Comment: вы хотите что бы пользователь нажимая backspace менял введенное значение и компонент показывал соответствующие варианты подходящие под ввод?

Comment: да, чтобы пользователь мог что то удалить к примеру

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ментейнер написал в ишью, что сейчас такой возможности нет

https://github.com/sagalbot/vue-select/issues/806